# C - Declare a file in function parameters

Tags: c, file, parameters, declare

so here is my problem :

```
int isopen()
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("myfile", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == 0)
        printf("file opening error");
    if (fd > 0)
       printf("file opening success");
    return(0);
}

int main(void)
{
   isopen();
    return(0);
}
```

Is use this code to check if this the open command worked, as i'm just starting to lurn how to use it.

Basically this code is working just fine, but I would like to declare the file I would like to open directly in the parameters of my function isopen.

I saw some other posts using main's argc and argv, but I really need to declare my file in the parameters of my function isopen, not using argc & argv.

Is it even possible ?

Thank you for your help, I'm quite lost here.

Comment: You mean to say, a hardcode file name?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm sorry, but what is a hardcore file name ?

Comment: I suggest you start by reading the man page for `open()` and get right the return value, before making the file name more general.

Comment: Something like `isopen("somfilename.txt")?`?

Comment: In `main` you don't call `isopen` but you call `size` whicht you didn't show BTW.

Comment: @WeatherVane I already red the man, and I know that the open function returns the file descriptor, I don't how knowing this piece of information is giving me any help wth using a file as a parameter ? I'm sorry..

Comment: @SouravGhosh Yup !

Comment: "Return Value ... returns a file descriptor for the opened file. A return value of -1 indicates an error;"

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry, I just modified my original function name for this post, and forgot to change it in the main function, editing that right away !

Comment: @MarilouCassar still wrong, try harder. Now you call the inextstant `myfile`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yup, I know that, I mean this isn't answering my question, I just preferred to print a string so I have more visual..

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but if you don't start with the correct use of the function, there is no point going further. It **returns -1** on error, and you have not trapped it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Haha, sorry. My mistake again.

Comment: @WeatherVane You would prefer to see something like " if function open returns -1, then return that there was error" ?

Comment: I would prefer to see `if (fd < 0) printf("file opening error"); else printf("file opening success"); return fd;`

Comment: @WeatherVane Sorry, but I won't do that as I'm not allowed to do it. I lurn at school 42 and we have a very strict norm, forbidding us to use a function directly in 'if' parameters. Sorry !

Comment: I have not the faintest idea what you are talking about, my code is almost exactly like yours except for the correct test, and returning a useful value from the function. Good luck with the lurning.

Comment: @WeatherVane It's just that I'm turning at a particular school that wants us to write our codes in a very strict manner, and what you told me to do is something forbidden ! Thanks for trying to help !

Comment: In that case why did you accept an answer almost identical to my comment?

Comment: @WeatherVane It don't understand, I don't feel like it's identical ? Well sorry, anyway, this question is answered, thanks for you advices !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but maybe you want this:

```
int isopen(const char *filename)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0)                           //BTW <<<<<<<<<<<<  fd < 0 here !!
        printf("file opening error"); 
    else                                  // else here
       printf("file opening success");

    return(0);
}


int main(void)
{
   isopen("myfile");
    return(0);
}
```

BTW, the `isopen` function as it stands here is still pretty useless as it just opens the file and throwing away `fd`.

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is exactly what I needed. Sorry for unclear instructions, I struggle a bit with english as it's not my mother language. And thanks again for the little help with my if conditions !

Comment: It's actually worse than useless - it leaks the file descriptor, leaving it open, and a process only has a limited number of available descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int isOpen(char *filename)
{
   return open(filename, O_RDONLY);
}

int main() 
{
    printf("%d\n", isOpen("/home/viswesn/file1.txt"));
    printf("%d\n", isOpen("file2.txt"));
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
    viswesn@viswesn:~$ cat /home/viswesn/file1.txt
    hello
    viswesn@viswesn:~$
    viswesn@viswesn:~$ cat /home/viswesn/file2.txt
    cat: /home/viswesn/file2.txt: No such file or directory
    viswesn@viswesn:~$
    viswesn@viswesn:~$ ./a.out
    3     <---------- File exist and it give file descriptor number '3'
                      STDIN-0, STDOUT-1, STDERR-2 are reserved and 
                      next file opened will start with 3 and it keeps going
    -1    <---------  File not found; so open gives -1 as error
```

Comment: Welcome and don't forgot to say "This answer is useful" ;)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do it so, sorry !

Comment: @MarilouCassar :-) don't write "his answer is useful" but rather upvote it !